# developing notification system based on stripe subscription service

Tags: stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

I have integrated stripe on my app. But now I'm stuck at building stripe's subscription service and notifications on user dashboard. Currently the app stores stripe's customer_id with one of the plans selected in user model on signup.

Now, I would like to build a notification system on user dashboard based on subscription periods like:-

1. The user should be notified 15 and 5 days before subscription expiry.
2. The user should be notified on subscription expiry.

Now, my questions are:-

1. what would be the appropriate way to handle above mentioned problems ?
2. What would be the best schema design keeping in mind the above problems ?

Better idea's will be heartly appreciated.

Rails version 4.1.4, stripe 1.20.3, ruby2.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below solution helps you:

Based on subscription plans expiry date and user signup date you can easily notify to user whenever you want. You can also go see the stripe webhooks reference at: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks